# Bash script errors: i in for loop gives 'no such file or directory'

Tags: bash, shell

Long story short, I need to write a shell script. The script will take a single command line argument which will be a directory path.
The script will then read each of the files in that directory and output it to standard output; the output will be in HTML and will be a table.

The files will be in this format:

```
owner sysadmin group
admin ajr
loc S-309
ser 18r97
comment noisy fan
```

What I have so far:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

cd "$@"
if [ test $? -ne 0]
then 
    exit 1
fi

filenames=$(ls "$@")
for i in $filenames
do
    while read item value
    do
        if [ $item="owner" ] || [ $item="admin" ] || [ $item="loc" ] || [ $item="ser"]
        then
            a[$item]=$value
        fi
    done < i
done

echo '<html>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<table border=1>'
echo '<tr><th>hostname</th><th>location</th><th>Admin</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>owner</th><tr>'
for i in filename
do
    echo '<tr><td>'$i'</td><td>'${i[loc]}'</td><td>${i[admin]}'</td><td>'${i[ser]}'</td><td>'${i[owner]}'</td><tr>'
done
echo 
echo '</table>'
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

The HTML isn't my main concern since I am just following a format given, with each of the values going in between. However, I am getting an error that I have no idea why:

```
invrep: line 10: i: no such file or directory
```

but I am using it in a loop. Why is it giving me this error?

Also to confirm, the directory that I used exists; I'm not sure if that has to do with anything though.

Comment: Your loop iterates once, with `i` set to the literal string `filenames`.

Comment: I fixed that part, and tried the code again, and it returned the same line, but 8 times, there were 8 files in that directory.

Comment: @NickGong You are reading from "input.txt" rather than "$i" each time

Comment: You also don't use `i` in the body of the loop. Do you mean to use `$i` instead of `input.txt`? Your code has quite a few problems to work out; this really isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that it is `< $i`, as in my (updated) answer.

Comment: Sorry about the hiccup there, it was meant to read from $i. I am a beginner to sh scripting, so I may have made several mistakes here or there. After fixing the $i, it doesn't give an error anymore, but it doesnt loop through the arrays, and only echos one.

Comment: See my answer for a brief explanation of that...you have your HTML generation in the wrong place(s).  It needs to be inside the `for i in $filenames` loop (or, at least, the per-file part should be; the head and tail sections need to be outside the loop, of course).

Comment: `[ $foo=bar ]` is wrong -- it needs to be either `[ "$foo" = bar ]` or `[[ $foo = bar ]]`. Otherwise, it will *always* return true, because it's testing if the string `$foo=bar` expands to something non-empty, which will always be true, because `=bar` is non-empty.

Comment: ...also, trying to write HTML from shell scripts is a bad idea in general -- if you go into irc.freenode.org #bash and ask about doing so, we'll tell you to use a different language, and rightly so: bash doesn't have any libraries available for doing entity escaping and other such detail work involved in making sure that your generated markup is actually valid.

Comment: ...see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses -- it mentions HTML and XML parsing as something bash isn't particularly well-suited-to, and really, the same applies to generation. This *can* be done with bash, but it involves using something like XMLStarlet. (the pyx and depyx subcommands come in useful here -- it's that, or xmlstarlet ed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Caveat Lector**: the code in the question has been edited. The code I commented on may not be the code you can see.*

---

Not directly the problem ([chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) diagnosed that in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640397/bash-script-errors-i-in-forloop-no-such-file-or-directory#comment32704564_21640397)), but:

```
cd "$@"
if [ test $? -ne 0]
then 
    exit 1
fi
```

has a variety of problems.  You don't verify that there's only one argument, and you pass all the arguments that are given to `cd`, which may just quietly ignore the surplus.  The `test` line should use either `[` or `test` but not both.  If you use `[`, the last argument must be `]` so you're missing a space:

```
if test $? -ne 0
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

However, you could short circuit that paragraph by:

```
cd "$@" || exit 1
```

(or you could drop the 1 even, though I'd leave it there).

You might want to consider:

```
case $# in
1) cd "$1" || exit 1;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 directory" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

This verifies that a single argument was passed and that it names a directory you can `cd` to.

Your looping code also has problems.  The `while` loop should be redirected from `"$i"` once you've fixed things up:

```
filenames=$(ls "$@")
for i in $filenames
do
    while read item value
    do
        if [ $item="owner" ] || [ $item="admin" ] || [ $item="loc" ] || [ $item="ser"]
        then
            a[$item]=$value
        fi
    done < $i
    # Print HTML here!! Not after this loop
done
```

Your HTML loop has a lot of problems too — notably using `$i` as an array instead of `$a`.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

case $# in
1) cd "$1" || exit 1;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 directory" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

echo '<html>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<table border=1>'
echo '<tr><th>hostname</th><th>location</th><th>Admin</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>owner</th><tr>'

filenames=$(ls "$@")
for i in $filenames
do
    while read item value
    do
        if [ $item="owner" ] || [ $item="admin" ] || [ $item="loc" ] || [ $item="ser"]
        then
            a[$item]=$value
        fi
    done < $i
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>${a[loc]}</td><td>${a[admin]}</td><td>${a[ser]}</td><td>${a[owner]}</td><tr>"
done

echo '</table>'
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

And that still doesn't fix the problem with using `ls` to generate a list of file names. For that, given the rest of the script, lose `filenames` altogether and use `for file in *` instead.  You then need to quote `$i` in the I/O redirection, too.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

case $# in
1) cd "$1" || exit 1;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 directory" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

echo '<html>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<table border=1>'
echo '<tr><th>hostname</th><th>location</th><th>Admin</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>owner</th><tr>'

for i in *
do
    while read item value
    do
        if [ $item = "owner" ] || [ $item = "admin" ] ||
           [ $item = "loc" ]   || [ $item="ser"]
        then
            a[$item]=$value
        fi
    done < "$i"
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>${a[loc]}</td><td>${a[admin]}</td><td>${a[ser]}</td><td>${a[owner]}</td><tr>"
done

echo '</table>'
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

(Also fixed spacing in the `if` statement in the loops.  The code is still not very elegant, but it is somewhat related to the original code.)

Comment: I see what I did wrong there, instead of printing them in the same loop I decided to write another loop to print the html, thanks for the headsup! you helped me identify the problems in my code, even though I didn't do it right in the first place.

Comment: Just finished reading your update, question, does "for file in *" take care of file names with special characters and spaces in them?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The globbing operator `*` generates a list of file names and preserves the spacing within the names.  The same applies to more complicated patterns, too.

Comment: Are you working with [Bitcoin Barron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3258285/bitcoin-barron)?  See [Using multiple `sed` commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639949/using-multiple-sed-commands/21640683#21640683).

Comment: haha ya, most likely we are in the same course, doing an exercise, but I guess we decided to approach it through different ways. Also for the cd "$@" testing part, I was thinking of using that to check the directory, it could be non existent or permission denied, and both being -ne 0 will exit the program.

Comment: There is one problem, the echo in the above code (last block), will print the array from the last loop if the current one is empty. Lets say the current file has nothing at admin, it will print the value from the last file. I tried using unset to clear the array but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Quoting the Bash reference manual on [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays): _The `unset` builtin is used to destroy arrays. `unset name[subscript]` destroys the array element at index_ subscript. _Care must be taken to avoid unwanted side effects caused by filename expansion. `unset name`, where_ name _is an array, removes the entire array. A subscript of ‘*’ or ‘@’ also removes the entire array._

Comment: When fixed, the test you wrote will work OK, but the `cd "$1" || exit` is probably more idiomatic (and certainly more compact) — or `if cd "$1"; then : OK; else exit; fi` but the need to use `else` makes it less desirable.

Comment: Ya, i found unset as well, I put in `unset a` right before `while read item value` to unset it for the next loop, even tried putting it after the echo, yet somehow it still outputs a value from the previous array if the current one is empty.

Comment: `unset a` or `unset ${a[*]}` should do the trick, but it seems to be a little more complex.  This seems to work: `for i in 1 2 3;
do
    unset a;
    declare -A a;
    for j in a b c $i;
    do a[$j]="$i$j";
    done;
    for k in ${!a[@]};
    do echo "$k = ${a[$k]}";
    done;
done`.  The `unset` plus `declare -A` seemed to be necessary.  There might be neater ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I just went with quite a unproductive way for this one, i did a search for key words in the file and if they were not present I would unset the array indexed at that location. It worked, I know it is very unproductive D: and thanks for all the help on this problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
filenames=$(ls "$@")
```

is wrong, and should never be used by anyone. See the first entry in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, or the entire page http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

If your argument list is a set of directories, the inner loop would look more like this:

```
declare -A a
for dir in "$@"; do
  for i in "$dir/"*; do
    while read -r item value; do
      case $item in
        owner|admin|loc|ser)
          a[$item]=$value
          ;;
       esac
     done <"$i"
  done
done
```

Comment: +1 Was about to post the same thing. Should also probably be noted that op should check if file is an actual file (not a dir/link) and whatever other crieteria he is using to match input files.

Comment: Yes, but that's probably not what's causing the problem. `filenames=$(ls "$@")` is likely to work as intended if all the arguments are names of files in the current directory, and none of the names contain any special characters such as space. Which makes it worse in a way, because it's an error you might not find in testing or simple use.

Comment: Oh i see, I skimmed through the page you linked me, will read it in depth once I get home. I am really new to shell scripting so I am pretty bad at this D: thanks for the help!

Comment: @KeithThompson ...but several other changes I made in here _are_ corresponding with real issues -- for instance, using `declare -A` with the associative array.