# Command grouping in sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I do not understand the command grouping in sed scripts. We use curly braces to  group commands. I found some information in the first answer to the following question: 
[Using multiple sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639949/using-multiple-sed-commands).
 But I still do not understand this properly. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
/Number/ s/N/n/;s/r//
```

Then `r`s will be removed on all lines, not only those containing `Number`. But, if you use

```
/Number/{s/N/n/;s/r//}
```

then `r`s will be removed only from lines containing `Number`.

Comment: Also, in posix version, you need to add a `;` before the closing  braces or a new line (a real one, not `\n`)